# How to customize fonts for PowerBI card visual labels

Tags: fonts, powerbi, dashboard, powerbi-desktop

For a company dashboard in PowerBI I need to use the specific global font `Univers LT Std 45 Light` which is part of the Windows 10 standard fonts, however, it is not accessible in PowerBI Desktop by default.
From [sources online](https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-fonts-in-power-bi-everything-you-wanted-to-know-652163750ba3) including the original [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-report-themes), I have learned that customization can be achieved by importing theme.json files that contain styling parameters.

After a "successful" import, most of the visuals change their fonts automatically. For text boxes I had to change the font manually but at least it now shows up in the drop-down menu.
BUT: **Card visuals** only adapt their title, however, not the label itself. I really need all labels on my dashboard to have the same font, otherwise it looks weird. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my theme.json file:

```
{
   "name":"myTheme",
   "textClasses":{
      "label":{
         "fontFace":"Univers LT Std 45 Light"
      },
      "callout":{
         "fontFace":"Univers LT Std 45 Light"
      },
      "title":{
         "fontFace":"Univers LT Std 45 Light"
      },
      "header":{
         "fontFace":"Univers LT Std 45 Light"
      }
   },
   "visualStyles":{
        "*":{
            "*":{
                "*":[{
                    "fontFamily": "Univers LT Std 45 Light"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reinstalling the software and many tests I've found the answer: The theme import is working properly but ONLY for visuals that

- haven't been styled manually regarding the concerned attributes (fonts in my case)
- are added after the import of the theme.json

but not for ALL visuals as expected.

So easy solution: Just start over with your dashboard and import themes before adding anything. But seriously, I think this is a bug. Styles shouldn't be "frozen" just because they were changed at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong. For me, it is working perfectly.
There might be some glitch or else you have imported the theme and changed the data label after that because of which it would be taking different font then and after.
If this is the issue, import the file again and the changes are implemented as per expectation.

Comment: Did you create a card visual and go to the format pane, select data label and look at the font family there? Because I can reload and re-import as much as I want but there is no change in this field.

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Even if I'm giving different font, it is getting changed when I'm loading the theme again.

Comment: Thank you! That's good and bad news for me. Good because I understand the theme import. Bad because that means that something else is not working. I will test it on a fresh install.